# Quickly switch between fullscreen app instance in osx yostemite?

Tags: macos, vim

Fullscreen mode is awesome in osx, but when a process is launched with multiple instances, we can not switch between instances by using the shortcut command+`, is there any way to perform the same shortcut when instances are in fullscreen mode? (I am a macVim user and I want to do quick switch between multiple macVim instances running in fullscreen mode)

Comment: 1. Your question has nothing to do with programming. 2. Cmd+` doesn't work in fullscreen, no matter what application you are using, so it doesn't have anything to do with Vim or MacVim either. 3. Mac OS X creates a new "space" for each fullscreened window so you can use your space-navigation keys found in the "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab of the "Keyboard" preference pane. For me: Ctrl+Cmd+Right and Ctrl+Cmd+Left.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Vim question, as @romani said in the comment above.

There's a small OSX plugin I use called [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) that allows you to switch between windows using Option-Tab, much like you use Command-Tab to switch between applications. It continues to be usable even in Lion-style fullscreen windows, when Command-` is not available.